# Btn and Text aligen +do it responive

Tags: css, alignment

I have a question about aligning the button, I want to align the left button to the left / see the picture) and align the right button to the right, but I can't do that: /
the text beginning from the right and left should also be at the same starting point
also if I make the website responsive, then the text is lost and the button below disappears, can you possibly improve my css? she the picture, everything is written on it

Code HTML:

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Subrayada:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body>
   <section class="back">
      <div class="left-text"> <p style="font-size: 30px; padding-top: 40px;">20% OFF</p> 
         finer <br>smile
         <div class="btn-left">
            <input type="button" value="Aligen left" class="Anscheuen">
      
         </div>    
      </div>
         
      <div class="right-text"><h6>Lorem ipsum dolor </h6> <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit a? </p> 
      <div class="btn-right">
         <input type="button" value="Aligen right" class="Anscheuen">
   
      </div>     
    </div>



      <img src="https://demo.phlox.pro/shop-digital/wp-content/uploads/sites/127/2019/09/2.png" alt="" class="head">
   </section>

   
</body>
</html></pre>

    *{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.back{
   width: 80%;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 15% auto;
   background-color:#F42D38 ;
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 21px;
   color: #fff;
   display: flex;

}
.back:hover{
box-shadow:#F42D38 0 0  50px 0; /* للظل لحتى يطلع متناسب */ 
}

.btn-right{
   padding-right: 50px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end; 

   /* bottom: 10%;
   right: 10%;
   position: absolute; */


}
.btn-left{
display: block; 
  display: flex;
   justify-content:flex-start; 

   /* bottom: 10%;
   right: 10%;
   position: absolute; */


}

.Anscheuen{
   padding: 10px 20px;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: solid #fff 2px;
   color: #fff;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left:auto;
}
.Anscheuen:hover{

   padding: 10px 20px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border: solid #fff 2px;
   color: #F42D38;
   margin-top: 10px;
}

.head{
   width: 90%;
   top: 20%;
   left:45%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   position: absolute;
}
.left-text{
   flex-basis: 30%;
   font-size: 60px;
   padding-left: 4%;
   padding-top: 4%;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   line-height: 95%;
   justify-content: flex-end;

}
.right-text{
   flex-basis: 70%;
 padding-top: 6%;
padding-left: 30%;
padding-right: 50px;
}

.right-text h1{
   font-size: 40px;
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   line-height: 50px;
}
.right-text p{
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   line-height: 25px;
}
.right-text h6{
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   line-height: 50px;
}
@media (max-width:700px){


   .head{
      width: 150%;
      top: 10%;
      left: 57%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
   }

   .back{

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 600px;

   }


   .left-text{
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 30%;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   }

   .right-text{
    padding-top: 8%;
    padding: 5% 5%;   
}
   

   .right-text h1{
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   line-height: 30px;
}
   .right-text p{
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   line-height: 14px;
}
   .right-text h6{
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   line-height: 50px;
}

}
```

the image
https://ibb.co/RHPMR3m

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.back {
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 15% auto;
  background-color: #F42D38;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;

}

.back:hover {
  box-shadow: #F42D38 0 0 50px 0;
  /* للظل لحتى يطلع متناسب */
}

.btn-right {
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  /* bottom: 10%;
   right: 10%;
   position: absolute; */


}

.btn-left {
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;

  /* bottom: 10%;
   right: 10%;
   position: absolute; */


}

.Anscheuen {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid #fff 2px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.Anscheuen:hover {

  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid #fff 2px;
  color: #F42D38;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.head {
  width: 90%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.left-text {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  line-height: 95%;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}

.right-text {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.right-text h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.right-text p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.right-text h6 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width:700px) {

.Anscheuen {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid #fff 2px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
  .head {
    width: 150%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 57%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .back {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 600px;

  }


  .left-text {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-top: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }

  .right-text {
    padding-top: 8%;
    padding: 5% 5%;
  }


  .right-text h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  .right-text p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    line-height: 14px;
  }

  .right-text h6 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Subrayada:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="back">
      <div class="left-text">
        <p style="font-size: 30px; padding-top: 40px;">20% OFF</p>
        finer <br>smile
        <div class="btn-left">
          <input type="button" value="Aligen left" class="Anscheuen">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="right-text">
        <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor </h6>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum, dolor sit amet consecteturipsum, dolor sit a? </p>
        <div class="btn-right">
          <input type="button" value="Aligen right" class="Anscheuen">

        </div>
      </div>



      <img src="https://demo.phlox.pro/shop-digital/wp-content/uploads/sites/127/2019/09/2.png" alt="" class="head">
    </section>


  </body>

</html>
```